# How to Get Params Value in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I Need to Get Dob Params in Joomla

Params in DB

```
{"dob":{"label":"Date of Birth","value":"27-11-1987"},"email":{"label":"Email","value":"asktokaje007@gmail.com"}}
```

My code :

```
$params = new JRegistry();

$params->loadString($orderinfo->all_billing);

$processed_variables['test123'] = $params->get('dob' ,'value');
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: How to Display DOB Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter for `get` is for default value, not for key.

`$params->get('dob');` will give you `stdClass` object.

So:

```
$dob = $params->get('dob');
$processed_variables['test123'] = $dob->value;
```

Is probably what you are looking for. Remember to check if there exists key like `value`. If you won't check it and it dosen't exist, you will get an error.

Comment: I Got Following Error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I Got Following : object(stdClass)#808 (2) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(12) "Fødselsdato"
  ["value"]=>
  string(10) "04-08-1934"
}

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.